# What data is bitmoji keyboard collecting about me?

Tags: mobile, keyloggers

Bitmoji is a virtual keyboard for iOS and Android to create personalized emojis (very paraphrased). I've found a few blogs looking at the permissions it requests and the privacy policy that it shares with Snapchat:

- https://www.makeuseof.com/tag/bitmoji-threat-privacy/
- https://nordvpn.com/blog/bitmoji-keyboard-app-privacy/

And this one about 3rd party keyboards in general with regard to uploading what you type:

- https://zeltser.com/third-party-keyboards-security/

---

I'm looking for something a bit more technical about what it might be doing in the background when not being actively used.

**What *could* it do?:** According to the iOS / Android developer docs, what can a virtual keyboard do given the permissions Bitmoji asks for? Can it collect keystrokes when I'm using other keyboards (like the built-in one)? Can it log which apps I use, which websites I visit, etc? Other nefarious things?

**(Bonus points) What *does* it do?:** Has anyone published a security analysis of Bitmoji; decompiling the apk to see what system calls it uses? Traffic analysis? etc?

Comment: I can answer part A, but not part B. Do you want an answer that explains what it is technically capable of given the permissions it has? I imagine no one has actually done a security audit or other analysis of the software, meaning you'd likely have to pay for that or do it yourself.

Comment: Yeah, part B might be wishful thinking...